# Bayes Occam Razor

Tags: self-study, bayesian, model-selection

I was reading this paper here: http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/papers/05occam/occam.pdf

To me it seems there is a mistake, and I would like a clarification if anyone knows. It states towards the end `"The model simply defines a single distribution over data sets, assigning them all probability 1/152."` I think the fraction is wrong. Shouldn't it be 1/512 instead? Is it just a typo or something else I am missing?

Comment: In general, you want to include the entirety of your question in the question rather than referencing an external paper. You should include all relevant material in the question itself, if possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a rather straightforward correction to a simple typo that does not bring added value to any other reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem to just be a typo. The phrase should read "The model simply defines a single distribution over data sets, assigning them all probability 1/512."